# KEYCLOAK unknown authenticator error - Client Adapter installed

Tags: tomcat8, keycloak

I am trying to setup Keycloak with Tomcat 8.

I followed the instruction carefully.  I downloaded the Client Adapter for Tomcat8 and copied all the jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory.  I modified my web.xml login-config to use KEYCLOAK.  Yet when I started Tomcat I kept getting Severe Error Unknown Authenticator??

Anywhere I googled everyone said you have to install the Client Adapter but.. in my case IT IS ALREADY THERE!!! HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to create a META-INF directory beside the WEB-INF and put a file named `context.xml` into it:

[image]

The contents of this file has to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
</Context>
```

This is not needed if you deploy the war into WildFly. I had the same problem when I tried to transfer a well working webApp from WildFly to Tomcat.